# What sites can we use to help promote this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

What bloggers, forms, tweeters, etc can we use to try and help promote this site?

Comment: For the sake of ease of use, could we collect all the links into 1 post. We can all do our bit then, and eliminate dupes.

Comment: @Daniel well, you could have made the big list by yourself and mark it as a community wiki answer, but I've now made it for you :-)

Comment: I was on a tight schedule ;) Cheers :) - Upvoted!

Comment: We can post lists all day but the follow through is what counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[Daniel Hanly](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users/227/daniel-hanly):

> For the sake of ease of use, could we collect all the links into 1 post. We can all do our bit then, and eliminate dupes.

(For even further convenience, please try to keep the list in alphabetical order.)

---

http://abduzeedo.com/user-news

http://www.creativepro.com

http://cssglobe.com (requires registration, free)

http://designm.ag/submit-community-news

http://www.GraphicDesignForum.com

http://www.InDesignSecrets.com

http://scriptandstyle.com/submit

http://www.underconsideration.com/quipsologies/

Answer (score 2):

Some popular design blogs have a "Community News" section where people can submit links of interest:

http://designm.ag/submit-community-news

http://cssglobe.com (requires registration, free)

http://scriptandstyle.com/submit

http://abduzeedo.com/user-news

Comment: http://www.underconsideration.com/quipsologies/

Answer (score 2):

The potential value of this site needs to be sold to designers who are very active in the "design" community and have a following. If we could get people like Marlaky, Zeldman, Grace Smith, etc to stop by and give a few answers it would go a long way.

WordPress.StackExchange really started getting noticed when some of the core contributors and Automattic employees started contributing.

Getting a mention on Smashing Magazine could blow this site up overnight.  The beta users should be actively promoting it all the time.

Another idea is to take answers you spent a lot of time on and turn them into blog posts if you have a blog.

Answer (score 1):

These would be good places, I think. They are also good resources.

[CreativePro.com](http://www.creativepro.com)

[InDesignSecrets.com](http://www.InDesignSecrets.com)

[GraphicDesignForum.com](http://www.GraphicDesignForum.com)

There are also assorted listservs like InDesign-Talk (now indesign-talk@googlegroups.com) and WebWeavers (also now on Google Groups: webweavers@googlgroups.com).